# If we have $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ and a filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_t^W; 0 \leq t \leq T\},$ how can we justify that $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{F}_T$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $T>0.$ Also, let $\{B_t; 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ be a Brownian motion that generates the filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_t^W; 0 \leq t \leq T\}.$ I have read in a couple of math finance books: "assume $\mathscr{F}_T^W = \mathscr{F}...".$ How can we justify this assumption?

In order to define a B.M. we need a probability space, right? So we start with a probability space with some sigma-algebra defined on Ω and then we define a B.M. that generates the filtration. And then we replace the original sigma-algebra by $\mathscr{F}_T$? How can we do that? It seems to me like "the chicken or the egg".

Comment: If only the process $B$ is of interest, then all of it is measurable relative to $\mathscr{F}_T.$ Hence, the extra information in $\mathscr{F}$ is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question. In order to define a B.M. we need a probability space, right? So we start with a probability space with some sigma-algebra defined on $\Omega$ and then we define a B.M. that generates the filtration. And then we replace the original sigma-algebra by $\mathscr{F}_T$? How can we do that?  It seems to me like the egg and the chicken.

Comment: Saying "assume $\mathcal F = \mathcal F_T$" seems wrong to me. Finance-oriented books may not be the most rigorous mathematically, and so they may use abuses of notation like this. Have you see this notion in a text specifically written about Brownian motion and other stochastic processes?

Comment: @Math1000: I haven't studied a proper book in stochastic analysis. I've had a look at a couple of them but this issue doesn't arise because they always consider $\{B_t \}_{t \geq 0}.$

Comment: This book I'm talking about is supposed to be more rigorous than the classical "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II" from Steven Shreve. I quote straight from the book: "In our pricing model $H$ is a r.v. defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ supporting the Wiener process $W,$ equipped with its natural filtration $(\mathscr{F}_t^W)_{t \in [0,T]},$ and we may assume in addition that $\mathscr{F}_T^W = \mathscr{F}$."

Comment: Ah, I recall in Shreve that some of the mathematics is not completely rigorous. So that would probably explain some of the descrepancies.

Comment: No, this book I'm talking about is not from Shreve. This one is from Capinski, it's supposed to be more rigorous.